# How to find the package name of React Native App

Tags: android, react-native, expo, systrace

I'm trying to profiling my React Native App (created by Expo CLI) by using `systrace`. I followed this tutorial https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#profiling and I knew how to run `systrace` with this line of code: `<path_to_android_sdk>/platform-tools/systrace/systrace.py --time=10 -o trace.html sched gfx view -a <your_package_name>`. The tutorial show me how to get `your_package_name` by finding it in `AndroidManifest.xml` in my project folder. But when I search for it I found that so many `AndroidManifest.xml` files in different sub-directories in my project folder. Each of them has different package name and I don't know which one is right to run `systrace` in my app. Can anyone tell me where I can find the right package name to run `systrace` ?

Comment: Were you able to find the package name?

Answer (score 0):

That documentation you've followed on is for react-native which doesn't support by Expo, try to read and follow this [Expo Systrace](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v33.0.0/react-native/systrace/) documentation.

Hope this helps.